# No internet connection in a VM Guest

Tags: vmware-player

I am using VMWare. I am using a default NAT setting. I am unable to ping to an external url from within the guest OS. The firewall on the host Windows OS is the Symantec Endpoint Protection and I have created some firewall rules for allowing network traffic on ports 22, 80, 53 etc. I am still unable to ping.

I tried changing the network setting to Bridged but then starting the VM os gives an error message 'Connectivity issues detected'

Can someone help?

Comment: `ping` does not use TCP, so the TCP rules do not apply to it. `ping` uses ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol); you cannot `ping` a URL, you can only `ping` a host, i.e., a computer.

Answer (score 0):

I reimported the image and started the VM guest it seems it is working fine.